# Anyone good with Email Coding?

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

I'm working on a custom email, coding it myself for my boss I haven't done this before and I know it can be tricky because you have to use tables more etc..

My problem is that I'm trying to add a small image to a div or a `<td>` that is on top of a color and placed in the top right corner.

When I test using hotmail its not there but when I preview in a browser its working. I could create the image as a background but the problem with that is the content area it'll be in will change size when my boss fills in the content in that area.

I basically want the content area to look like a piece of paper with a little curl on it.

So I'm a bit struck on how to work around this or what would be the best solution, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Well, HTML email sucks. It's basically never going to look the same everywhere. To help out though, you could try reading through this:

http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/

It's a collection of best practices that should help to get things as similar as possible.

You'll also want to use `table`s for layout (yep, I know…), and minimise CSS use to inline styles or ideally, the crappy old HTML1/2/3/4 methods (like the `font` tag).

Did I mention that HTML email sucks yet?

Comment: +1 html email sucks. I did a similar project recently, and no matter what  I said no one could fathom HTML email being a poor choice. Even when offered a pdf generated on the fly. http://24ways.org/2009/rock-solid-html-emails helped me a bit

Comment: even the question is not well written, this answer is not an answer at all. and that make it more worse.

Answer (score 2):

I also had some luck reviewing

http://24ways.org/2009/rock-solid-html-emails

1. Basically pretend it is 1997 again. If you don't remember writing HTML in the late 90s good for you. 
   But, you are correct more tables where you would have previously relied on css.
2. review in multiple email services and clients. I was surprised to see that outlook displayed my page better than gmail. Gmail did a very poor job
3. keep it simple. Same advice my ENG 101 professor had on writing papers for his classes. But, keeping it simple will save you many headaches. now is not the time to show off all that fancy css3. Consider even creating a pdf. I have herd good things about iText for java and on the fly pdf generation.
4. use inline css. I know it feels wrong, and dirty, but it solved a lot of my css problems.
5. has anyone told you that HTML sucks yet?